# Android different size for buttons on different screens, layouts dont find *dpi folders

Tags: android, image, button, layout, size

I put images(ImageButtons) with diffrent size to xxdpi, xdpi, hdpi, mdpi. Created different layout folders. layout, layout-normal, layout-large, layout-xlarge. And dublicate main.xml with Imagebuttons in each. But Imagebuttons look like the same size(hdpi) in each layout resolution. WHat`s wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/normal_login"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edLogin"
        android:layout_width="380dp"
         android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="176dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/login_help" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edBirth"
        android:layout_width="246dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edLogin"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edLogin"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edLogin"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/birth" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edPass"
        android:layout_width="246dp"
         android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edBirth"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edBirth"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edBirth"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/pass" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btCancel"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edPass"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/login_bt_cancel" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btOk"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edPass"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btCancel"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/login_bt_ok" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btRecover"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btOk"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btOk"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="Recover Password"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: put your code here so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following to your Manifest.xml file:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
  android:normalScreens="true" 
  android:largeScreens="true"
  android:xlargeScreens="true"
  android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi

Comment: yeap i use it) for images

Answer (score 0):

```
 android:layout_width="180dp"
 android:layout_height="60dp"
```

please it set it to wrap content.
you define fix size to imageButton so you can not see the images different size in other mobile

```
change to this
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```